# How to parse SOAP XML in SQL Server and show as table data

Tags: sql-server, xml, soap

Hi I have sample data in SOAP XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns0:Context xmlns:ns0="http://service.PUBG.com/entity/message/2007/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <messageId>N455D</messageId>
        <refToMessageId>142323</refToMessageId>
        <Timestamp>2018-08-08T23:00:11.282Z</Timestamp>
        <applicationId>PUBG</applicationId>
        <hostName>UNKNOWN</hostName>
    </ns0:Context>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns2:searchResponseResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.PubG.com/provider/gpow/bankLookup/PubGLookUpService/2013/" xmlns:ns4="http://service.PubG.com/provider/gpow/bankLookup/PubGLookUpService/2015/">
        <ns4:PubGDetails>
            <ns4:Name>PUBG Roll</ns4:Name>
        </ns4:PubGDetails>
        <ns4:PubGCode>xxxxxxx</ns4:PubGCode>
        <ns4:countryCode>US</ns4:countryCode>
        <ns4:address>
            <ns4:physicalAddress1>XXX PARK AVENUE</ns4:physicalAddress1>
        </ns4:address>
        <ns4:zipCode>123456</ns4:zipCode>
        <ns4:countryName>USA</ns4:countryName>
        <ns4:parentPubGCode>0</ns4:parentPubGCode>
        <ns4:modificationInd>A</ns4:modificationInd>
        <ns4:modificationDate>2017-05-02</ns4:modificationDate>
    </ns2:searchResponseResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

';

I have written code like this  to get in table format  :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap,
    'http://service.PubG.com/provider/gpow/bankLookup/PubGLookUpService/2013/' AS ns2,
    'http://service.PubG.com/provider/gpow/bankLookup/PubGLookUpService/2015/' AS ns4,
    'http://service.PUBG.com/entity/message/2007/' as ns0), rs AS
(
   SELECT col.value('(soap:Header/ns0:Context/messageId)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS messageId
   , col.value('(soap:Header/ns0:Context/refToMessageId)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS refToMessageId
   , col.value('(soap:Header/ns0:Context/Timestamp)[1]','DATE') AS [Timestamp]
   , col.value('(soap:Header/ns0:Context/applicationId)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS applicationId
   , col.value('(soap:Header/ns0:Context/hostName)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS hostName
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:PubGDetails/ns4:Name)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS PubGDetails
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:PubGCode)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS PubGCode
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:countryCode)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS countryCode
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:address/ns4:physicalAddress1)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [Address]
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:zipCode)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS zipCode
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:countryName)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS countryName
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:parentPubGCode)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS parentPubGCode
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:modificationInd)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS modificationInd
   , col.value('(soap:Body/ns2:searchResponseResponse/ns4:modificationDate)[1]','DATE') AS modificationDate
   FROM @xml.nodes('/soap:Envelope') AS tab(col)
)
SELECT * FROM rs;
```

I'm getting error like this :

```
Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 4, character 2, illegal qualified name character
```

How to get output like this :

```
messageId   refToMessageId  Timestamp   applicationId   hostName    PubGDetails PubGCode    countryCode address zipCode countryName parentPubGCode  modificationInd modificationDate
N455D        142323         8/8/2018      PUBG          UNKNOWN      PUBG Roll        xxxxxxxxx   us       XXX     PARK AVENUE           123456      USA    0   A   5/2/2017
```

Comment: The error is in your XML, not your SQL. Line 4 starts with `<soap:Header`, but `<soapenv:Envelope` hasn't been closed yet. You can't start a new tag until the previous has been closed. `<parent<child><name>Harry</name></child></parent>`  isn't valid XML. Fix your XML.

Comment: how we need to modify that I'm unable to clear that one @Larnu

Comment: Looking through that XML, there are so many problems with it... Multiple unclosed nodes, undeclared namespaced (`ns4` isn't declared, but appears latter on). The process you need to fix is whatever created that XML; which we can't help you with as we have no context of that.

Comment: The `searchResponseResponse` tag isn't closed either (you close it with `searchPubGResponse`). But, like I said, the problem isn't your XML, it's the XML itself; which we can't help with here.

Comment: @Larnu I have modified the XML and if some thing tags missed you can provide that's huge XML for questioning purpose I have trimmed

Comment: Like i said, fix the XML, fix the problem: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1b3a5d9a2cbf5ce2b215bd5c4ed25fa). I've added a load of comments within the top comments. The SQL still returns no data as you haven't declared your XML Namespaces in the SQL, but it seems silly to provide an answer on how to get data from the XML I fixed, when it won't work against the (invalid) XML you have supplied. Once you can provide valid XMl, then we can help you use SQL to extract data from it. I suggest asking about the process you use to create the XML in a new question.